# Facebook Review and Submission IOS

Tags: ios, facebook, unity-game-engine, review, submission

My game uses facebook scores, so I need publish_actions, and I need to send my game to review. Facebook ask for apk file and simulator build (IOS), but with some unty3d plugins it's not possible to make a simulator build, and my game it's not live (yet).

I can send an ipa from testflight, but I can't contact with facebook team, how can I solve this problem

Thank you!!

Comment: Building in simulator shouldn't be a problem. You can define multiple targets in Xcode and then exclude the non-building plugins. That will probably result in an unusable app, but it would build. I've done that a few times for customers and normally it just results in two or three screens not working. And that would probably ok for Facebook. If you can attach an .ipa-file they can test that functions with a real device.

Comment: Juan, is there a chance you could send them an android build?  .apk  It's so much easier to send around android builds.

Comment: If you can't send in a simulator build they should also be fine with you providing a screen cast that shows how you will use the permissions